# Data truncation or corruption with ZendService and S3?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

**OVERVIEW**

- When I download the image with S3 Browser for Windows, the MD5 hash of the downloaded  file is correct.
- When I download the image via `ZendService\Amazon\S3`, the MD5 hash is INCORRECT.

**QUESTION**

Has anyone had problems with data truncation or corruption when pulling from S3 through the `ZendService\Amazon` library?  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

**DETAILS**

We employ Amazon S3 with the `ZendService\Amazon` library to push and pull full-size and thumbnail images, as well as PDF files.  Recently, we started to implement a PDF export for some of our documents.  As some of you may know, `ZendPdf` can be exceptionally finicky when it comes to malformed images.  The same images pulled via S3 load in browsers without a hitch.  As we developed this feature, we started to notice that images and PDFs inserted into `ZendPdf` worked in only a minority of cases.  Many of our images were causing exceptions or coming back with artifacts.

As I dug deeper, I compared the MD5 hash of the file on S3 with the file being served through the `ZendService\Amazon` library.  While the file attributes were correct, the file contents were slightly different.  I tested this same feature with our filesystem adapter, and it worked fine.  I also tested a different S3 client (Windows application), and found that the file worked fine there too (i.e. the hashes matched).  The problem seems to be related to the `ZendService\Amazon` library in some way.